# Why isn't `np.linalg.eig` returning a unitary matrix when I try to diagonalize a symmetric matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvector

Using Python, I created a symmetric matrix `X`, and diagonalized it using the code `Lambda, U = np.linalg.eig(X)`. My understanding is: since `X` is symmetric, `U` should be unitary, but I am finding that this is not the case, as `U` has eigenvalues that don't have absolute value `1`, which also means that this is not a scaling issue either. My question is why is `U` not unitary?

---

Here is a minimum reproducible example to see what I am getting:

```
import numpy as np

#Symmetric matrix, which should be diagonalized by unitary
X = np.array([[-1.1918157 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09852097,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -1.1918157 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.09852097,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -1.08529969,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.07826825,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -1.08529969,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07826825],
       [ 0.09852097,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -1.00585682,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.09852097,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        -1.00585682,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07826825,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        , -0.98276093,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.07826825,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        , -0.98276093]])

#check if X is symmetric
assert np.linalg.norm(X - X.conj().T) == 0

#diagonalize X
Lambda, U = np.linalg.eig(X)

#check if U is unitary
print(
    np.allclose(U @ U.conj().T, np.identity(U.shape[0])),
    np.allclose(U.conj().T,     np.linalg.inv(U))
)

#Since the above returns false, how non-unitary is it?
print(
    np.linalg.norm(U @ U.conj().T - np.identity(U.shape[0])),
    np.linalg.norm(U.conj().T - np.linalg.inv(U))
)
```

The output of the above code is:

```
False False
0.994793051566498 1.1641788210519939
```

Answer (score 0):

It's never guaranteed to return a unitary matrix.

```py
#diagonalize X
Lambda, U = np.linalg.eig(X)
```

From this line of code, you are finding eigenvalues of `X` (stored in `Lambda`) and its **right eigenvectors** (stored in matrix `U`). See [the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

The only unitary things here are the eigenvectors, which are the *columns* of `U`.

```py
In [4]: np.linalg.norm(U, axis=0)
Out[4]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Read more about eigenvalues and eigenvectors: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_matrices), [wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html)